# Nebular menu click refreshing page component Issue

Tags: angular, angular7, nebular

I am using nebular menu in my application, Where I am facing an issue like when I click on menu item its automatically scroll up to top of page and closing/expanding once again which means page.component.ts are hitting again when trying to redirect page.

pages-menu.ts

```
export const userMenu: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: "Menu1",
    icon: "nb-person",
    children: [
      {
        title: "SubMenu1",
        link: "/pages/forms/Sub-Menu1"
      },
      {
        title: "SubMenu2",
        link: "/pages/forms/Sub-Menu2"
      }
    ]
```

And If we call this menu.ts variable in pages.component.ts

```
menu: any
constructor(){
this.menu = userMenu
}
```

This works fine. But if I want to make my menu dynamic like show/hide based on some user roles and instead of exporting from menu.ts directly assign menu list in pages.component.ts file Im facing an issue like onclick of each menu item its refreshing entire component and dragging sidebar menu scrolls to top and refreshing takes place.

pages.component.ts

```
menu: NbMenuItem[]
this.menu = [
      {
        title: "Menu1",
        icon: "nb-person",
        children: [
          {
            title: "SubMenu1",
            link: "/pages/forms/Sub-Menu1"
          },
          {
            title: "SubMenu2",
            link: "/pages/forms/Sub-Menu2"
          }
        ],
"hidden" : this.available_groups.some(v => ['Admin'].includes(v)) ? false : true
```

Please someone guide me on this issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to build your menu only after you get the roles. You will set this.menu to [] by default.

Have a function get the user from your backend service and create a function to build your menu.

```
menu: NbMenuItem[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
 this.getUser();
}

getUser() {
 call your api to get user with roles and then call buildMenuByRole(role)
}

buildMenuByRole(role: any) { <-- use an interface for role
   this.menu = [
    {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'home-outline',
        link: '/pages/dashboard',
        hidden: (role && (role.findIndex(x => x.roleID === Roles.SystemAdministrator ||
                                              x.roleID === Roles.ITUser) !== -1)) ? false : true,
        home: true,
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am creating menu structure also dynamic with the help of API. After created menu json, both the manual created json and export const exactly looks same. But instead of putting external const value I assigned manually created array value in this.menu = this.Arr which results refreshing of menu again. Can you help me what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this on a online code platform like stackblitz?

Comment: Brian, I am not able to reproduce exact issue with this stackblitz but way of handling code is exactly same . I am getting json from api which is in static input.json from there I'm creating menu exactly same structure of nebular and assigning to menu variable.

Comment: I found one more thing, to make dynamic after taking data from api I am using page refresh , before applying refresh menu works perfectly fine , after page refreshing I kinda face issue like scroll to top nd menu refreshes on each click

this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    this._router.navigate(['/same-route'])